# Unity 2021 Can't Build In IL2CPP

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I have installed IL2CPP plugin for Unity 2021.3.8f1 and have installed the newest version of Visual Studio Community 2022 from the official website but Unity still produces an error when building a Windows build using IL2CPP.

What can I do to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't know the OS, check the requirements of corresponding OS in this docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/system-requirements.html

Comment: Are you on a machine with a 32-Bit processor by any chance?

Comment: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor